# MYSQL Modify Column Data Type Script with Checking of Current Column Data Type

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, alter-table

I have here a mysql script which alters my 'Job' table and changes the DESCRIPTION column data type to TEXT. However, I have this script together with all the other scripts which are sometimes run multiple times.
My question is, what do I need to add to my script so that it would check if the data type of DESCRIPTION column is already TEXT or not? This script takes too long to execute due to huge data and I don't want it to be executed again if the DESCRIPTION column has already been changed to TEXT.

```
ALTER TABLE Job
MODIFY DESCRIPTION TEXT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
AND
  TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND 
 COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME';
```

This will give you datatype of asked column.

Using If condition you can run your alter table command;

Comment: This could work. Though I replaced {TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'} to {TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()} to make it work on all our DB copies. I'm trying it out now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped. :D

Comment: Glad that it worked, Please mark it as right if possible :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. It's a long way but it worked. It needs to be in a stored procedure. Thanks for your help @shahmanthan9. If you guys know a better way please post it here. Thanks!

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_JobUpdateDescriptionColumnType;

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_JobUpdateDescriptionColumnType()
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
             AND TABLE_NAME = 'Job'
             AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Description'
             AND DATA_TYPE = 'text' )
    THEN
        ALTER TABLE Job
        MODIFY Description TEXT;
    END IF;
END;

CALL sp_JobUpdateDescriptionColumnType;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_JobUpdateDescriptionColumnType;
```